# Couldn't generate PGP key, general error

Tags: gnupg, keyrings, openpgp

Now I'm using Ubuntu12.04.04 LTS.

I tried to create my gpg key with following steps on "Passwords and Keys" program.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know why this error was occurred.
According to I skipped some steps.

Comment: Here is a link to how to generate gpg on Ubuntu:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that error was occurred are following:

`~/.gnupg/*.gpg` files had read-only permissions.

Before I use this operation, I created a gpg key by using following commands.

```
sudo -s
gpg --gen-key
```

After that, I logged in regular user.

Thus, I hadn't the permissions to write `~/.gnupg/*.gpg` (it's owner is root) files.

The solution: I modified it's permission by using following commands so that I created gpg key successfully.

```
sudo -s
chown xxx ~/.gnupg/*.gpg
```